# Leading slash in URL path with base URL does not work

Tags: url, path, relative-path

I'm working on a plain html site on Godaddy (linux).

Client wants URLs to start with a slash, but adding the slash breaks the URL.

This works...

```
<img src="images/logo_cascade.png">
```

This does not...

```
<img src="/images/logo_cascade.png">
```

I tried adding a 'base url=""' both with and without a trailing slash, but no luck.

```
<base url="http://brinsterinc.com/cascade/" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What’s the URL of the document where you have this `img` element? `http://brinsterinc.com/cascade/`? `http://brinsterinc.com/cascade`? Something else? And what’s the URL of the image? `http://brinsterinc.com/cascade/images/logo_cascade.png`? `http://brinsterinc.com/images/logo_cascade.png`? Something else?

Comment: The image is here: http://brinsterinc.com/images/logo_cascade.png. The document calling the image is here: http://brinsterinc.com/cascade/index.html

Comment: On the current page, the logo has the URL `http://brinsterinc.com/cascade/images/logo_cascade.png`. Just to clear, is the image URL you mentioned (without `cascade/`) the correct one, or the live one?